# CodeIgniter and counting particular rows from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table in database:

```
id      |   int(25) Auto Increment   
game    |   int(10)  
user    |   int(9)   
own     |   int(11)  
userrate|   int(2)   
time    |   datetime
```

What I want now is to count rows with all the `own` types. I know it's hard to understand, so I'll post an example:

```
 - own: 1; count: 5;
 - own: 2; count: 3;
 - own: 4; count: 10;
```

etc.

My initial thought was to create different queries for every `own` (since it's only four of them), like this:

```
    $this->db->where('user',$user);
    $this->db->from('ownership');
    $this->db->where('own','1');

    $whole = $this->db->count_all_results();

    return $whole;
```

But I think that's not good at all. Can you suggest me the proper way?

Comment: The function you are looking for is called group_by().

Comment: I tried with `group_by` but it isn't what I am looking for. Let's say one user have couple of `own = 3` games in a table, `group_by` takes only one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. It's similar to @vearutop's solution, but it returns an array `own - count`.

Here's the model:

```
public function countRates($user) {
    $this->db->select('own, COUNT(own) as count');
    $this->db->where('user',$user);
    $this->db->from('ownership');
    $this->db->group_by('own');

    $q = $this->db->get();
    $q = $q->result_array();

    return $q;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just group result by own:

```
$res = $this->db->query("SELECT count(1) AS games,own FROM ownership WHERE user = ? GROUP BY own", array($user))->result_array();
```